# String checking on multiple types

Tags: python

I have a variable containing a string (extracted from a XML feed). The string value can be of type integer, date or string. I need to convert it from string to given data type. I am doing it this way but it is a little bit ugly so I am asking if there is a better technique. If I would checking for more types, I will end with very nested try - except blocks.

```
def normalize_availability(self, value):
    """
    Normalize the availability date.
    """
    try:
        val = int(value)
    except ValueError:
        try:
            val = datetime.datetime.strptime(value, '%Y-%m-%d')
        except (ValueError, TypeError):
            # Here could be another try - except block if more types needed
            val = value
```

Thanks!

Comment: What should this function return? Is it just checking if it's an int, date, or str, and returning True/False?

Comment: Return value is not important, the point is if there is a better solution to convert the string to a specific data type other way than nesting try - except multiple times. If I would check 4 data types I will have 3 levels of try-except blocks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a handy helper function.

```
def tryconvert(value, default, *types):
    """Converts value to one of the given types.  The first type that succeeds is
       used, so the types should be specified from most-picky to least-picky (e.g.
       int before float).  The default is returned if all types fail to convert
       the value.  The types needn't actually be types (any callable that takes a
       single argument and returns a value will work)."""
    value = value.strip()
    for t in types:
        try:
            return t(value)
        except (ValueError, TypeError):
            pass
    return default
```

Then write a function for parsing the date/time:

```
def parsedatetime(value, format="%Y-%m-%d")
    return datetime.datetime.striptime(value, format)
```

Now put 'em together:

```
value = tryconvert(value, None, parsedatetime, int)
```

Answer (score 0):

The right way would be to know from the xml what type each should be.  This would prevent things that happen to be numeric strings from ending up as an int, etc. But assuming that isn't possible.

for int type I prefer

```
if value.isdigit():
    val = int(value)
```

for the date, the only other way I can think of would be splitting it and looking at the parts, which would be messier then just letting the strptime raise an exception.

Comment: I definitely do **NOT** prefer this to `try-except`.   There are lots of integers which this would fail on:  `'-12'` is but one example.  `' 32'` is another.

Comment: @mgilson Why would you be getting ' 32'? I would expect that not to convert.  Yes I was assuming negative numbers as invalid.  But I find they usually are.  If not ... my bad.

Comment: but I like kindall's approach better ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
def normalize_availability(value):
    """
    Normalize the availability date.
    """
    val = value
    try:
        val = datetime.datetime.strptime(value, '%Y-%m-%d')
    except (ValueError):
        if value.strip(" -+").isdigit():
            val = int(value)

    return val
```